# Is there a package in R that helps fit a non-linear function (guassian) to data?

Tags: r, model-fitting

I have the following set of data:

```r
vec <- c(1.4381956731, 0.4555557271, 1.4489407791, 1.3887681853, 1.5854036256, 1.3919917171, 0.8090697153, -0.1209192112, 1.5107251387, 1.3914544618, 0.4260066855, -0.7307039781, 1.5628389029, 0.685500996, -0.3890096065, -1.3829319138, 1.3242975492, 0.9734698375, 1.2146974677, 1.4811760972, 0.1659751197, 1.3232230386, 2.1344785435, 2.0635608437, 1.0400894948, 0.6720696135, 0.4152615795, 1.2109366806, 0.5296969586, 0.8842854575, -0.0086328532, 0.0407946345, 0.5877205312, 2.0092980583, -0.0145426615, 1.5042780751, -0.0537622985, 1.0905914931, 1.2431719987, 1.5117996493, -0.0258250229, 0.4851047686, 0.9697090504, 1.2345759139, 1.6837213457, 1.6831840904, 0.9933482836, 0.3443438797, 1.2678857426, 1.3796348452, 0.494775364, 1.3893054406, -1.3829319138, 2.7109534817, 0.462540046, -1.3829319138, 0.9928110283, 2.1484471813, 1.5945369657, -1.3829319138, 2.4573689795, 1.7395958971, 0.0005004869, 0.0714181867, -0.2192369313, 0.2100300544, -1.3829319138, 0.0563750382, 0.8058461835, 1.3925289724, 0.9498306042, 1.6504115171, -0.6528019594, -0.3847115641, 0.5028341936, 0.8063834388, 2.8296869033, 2.2403178378, -1.3829319138, 2.606188698, 1.9996274629, 1.2737955509, 1.568211456, 1.4484035238, -0.3637586074, 0.1982104378, 0.1020417388, -0.6200293861, -1.3829319138, -0.0838485954, 0.0655083783, -1.1400925177, 0.2519359679, 0.7811324396, -0.0645074046, 1.3608309097, -0.5630803241, 0.4254694302, 2.0823647793, -0.0005740237, 0.0101710823, -0.2256839949, 2.3665728336, -1.3829319138, -0.1176956794, 1.1222895559, -1.3829319138, 0.1675868856, 0.1632888432, 0.2825595201, 0.6161950621, 0.7440618238, 1.0873679613, 1.1765523413, -1.3829319138, -0.2047310382, -1.3829319138, -0.074178, 1.6439644534, -1.3829319138, 0.2385045853, 1.1067091522, 0.8773011385, -1.3829319138, -1.3829319138, 1.9722274425, -1.3829319138, 1.6219369861, 1.322148528, 1.500517288, 1.791172406, 1.036865963, 0.3061987533, -0.0371073842, -0.4137233504, -0.3454919271, -0.1058760628, 0.9541286466, -0.8026961885, 0.4711361308, 1.0057051555, 0.9917365177, 0.9294149028, -0.134887849, 0.434065515, 1.2517680835, -1.3829319138, 1.4478662685, -0.2589938236, -0.1601388482, 0.0794770162, 0.7703873336, -0.3777272452, 1.1867601921, -0.2267585055, -1.219069047, 0.997646326, -1.3829319138, -0.1714212095, -0.5963901528, -1.3829319138, -0.2708134402, 0.9004031165, -1.3829319138, -0.4857155607, -0.0580603409, -0.2777977592, -0.8424530808, 0.2234614369, -0.0451662137, -1.3829319138, 0.205732012, 0.0064102952, 1.6557840701, -0.4518684768, -1.0756218815, 0.8708540749, -0.9225041207, -1.3179240224, -1.2899867467, 0.2787987329, -0.493237135, 0.9525168807, -0.2724252061, -1.2346494507, -0.0397936607, -0.8112922733, -0.0784760424, 0.3701321342, -1.3829319138, 0.835395225, -0.0709544682, -0.3062722901, 0.5221753844, -0.5517979628, -0.6947078729, -1.3829319138, -1.3829319138, -0.3390448635, -1.3829319138)

> vec
  [1]  1.4381956731  0.4555557271  1.4489407791  1.3887681853  1.5854036256  1.3919917171  0.8090697153 -0.1209192112  1.5107251387  1.3914544618  0.4260066855 -0.7307039781  1.5628389029  0.6855009960 -0.3890096065 -1.3829319138
 [17]  1.3242975492  0.9734698375  1.2146974677  1.4811760972  0.1659751197  1.3232230386  2.1344785435  2.0635608437  1.0400894948  0.6720696135  0.4152615795  1.2109366806  0.5296969586  0.8842854575 -0.0086328532  0.0407946345
 [33]  0.5877205312  2.0092980583 -0.0145426615  1.5042780751 -0.0537622985  1.0905914931  1.2431719987  1.5117996493 -0.0258250229  0.4851047686  0.9697090504  1.2345759139  1.6837213457  1.6831840904  0.9933482836  0.3443438797
 [49]  1.2678857426  1.3796348452  0.4947753640  1.3893054406 -1.3829319138  2.7109534817  0.4625400460 -1.3829319138  0.9928110283  2.1484471813  1.5945369657 -1.3829319138  2.4573689795  1.7395958971  0.0005004869  0.0714181867
 [65] -0.2192369313  0.2100300544 -1.3829319138  0.0563750382  0.8058461835  1.3925289724  0.9498306042  1.6504115171 -0.6528019594 -0.3847115641  0.5028341936  0.8063834388  2.8296869033  2.2403178378 -1.3829319138  2.6061886980
 [81]  1.9996274629  1.2737955509  1.5682114560  1.4484035238 -0.3637586074  0.1982104378  0.1020417388 -0.6200293861 -1.3829319138 -0.0838485954  0.0655083783 -1.1400925177  0.2519359679  0.7811324396 -0.0645074046  1.3608309097
 [97] -0.5630803241  0.4254694302  2.0823647793 -0.0005740237  0.0101710823 -0.2256839949  2.3665728336 -1.3829319138 -0.1176956794  1.1222895559 -1.3829319138  0.1675868856  0.1632888432  0.2825595201  0.6161950621  0.7440618238
[113]  1.0873679613  1.1765523413 -1.3829319138 -0.2047310382 -1.3829319138 -0.0741780000  1.6439644534 -1.3829319138  0.2385045853  1.1067091522  0.8773011385 -1.3829319138 -1.3829319138  1.9722274425 -1.3829319138  1.6219369861
[129]  1.3221485280  1.5005172880  1.7911724060  1.0368659630  0.3061987533 -0.0371073842 -0.4137233504 -0.3454919271 -0.1058760628  0.9541286466 -0.8026961885  0.4711361308  1.0057051555  0.9917365177  0.9294149028 -0.1348878490
[145]  0.4340655150  1.2517680835 -1.3829319138  1.4478662685 -0.2589938236 -0.1601388482  0.0794770162  0.7703873336 -0.3777272452  1.1867601921 -0.2267585055 -1.2190690470  0.9976463260 -1.3829319138 -0.1714212095 -0.5963901528
[161] -1.3829319138 -0.2708134402  0.9004031165 -1.3829319138 -0.4857155607 -0.0580603409 -0.2777977592 -0.8424530808  0.2234614369 -0.0451662137 -1.3829319138  0.2057320120  0.0064102952  1.6557840701 -0.4518684768 -1.0756218815
[177]  0.8708540749 -0.9225041207 -1.3179240224 -1.2899867467  0.2787987329 -0.4932371350  0.9525168807 -0.2724252061 -1.2346494507 -0.0397936607 -0.8112922733 -0.0784760424  0.3701321342 -1.3829319138  0.8353952250 -0.0709544682
[193] -0.3062722901  0.5221753844 -0.5517979628 -0.6947078729 -1.3829319138 -1.3829319138 -0.3390448635 -1.3829319138
```

This is what the density plot looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I sketched on three red curves because I believe the PDF of this data can be roughly approximated using a sum of three Gaussians:

```r
A1 * exp(-(data-mean1)**2/(2 * sigma1**2)) +
A2 * exp(-(data-mean2)**2/(2 * sigma2**2)) +
A3 * exp(-(data-mean3)**2/(2 * sigma3**2))
```

However, I don't really know how to go about fitting this function to the data. I understand that R has the `nls()`function, but I couldn't figure out how to use it with just a vector of data.

Edit: I can estimate the means and sigmas decently from the plot, so I really only need to fit 3 parameters. But I don't know the functions/package to use. I would assume it would look pretty similar to the way I would do it in gnuplot:

```
fit f(x) 'data.dat' using ... via ...
```

Comment: If you are wanting to try to estimate the underlying distributions a good search term would be mixture of Gaussians. Top of my head is mclust package but there are several

Comment: I tried to do this with `nor1mix` package (which is quite simple) but it had a lot of trouble, even playing around with different algorithms and cutpoints ...

Comment: @BenBolker Could you post the code and/or functions you used?

Comment: if  I can still find them ...

Answer (score 0):

The function you are fitting is the sum of the three - so there are 9 parameters - A1,mean1,sigma1 etc.

Personally I would pick the means off the plot rather than treat them as things to be estimated a part of a 9-parameter haul from the data. From your sketch above you could also take a pretty good stab at the sigmas.

Fitting a 9-parameter model to a vector of data can give strange results. Also the estimates in an A*exp(B) tend to ne horrible. Your fitting procedure will wander all over the place getting to a final place that may or may not make sense.

Comment: Given that I eyeball the means and sigmas (which I agree I can get pretty close with), how do I go about doing the fitting?